# "no such file or directory" installing upstream ruby-rvm?

Tags: software-installation, rvm

I'm currently on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have ruby version 1.9. 3 installed. I want to install the latest ruby version as I need it for SASS compass to do my front end work. I did research and noticed that its best to just use RVM (ruby version manager) to manage your ruby versions.

I'm trying to install rvm, but I'm have a frustratingly hard time of doing it as all the instructions online seem to have a quirk here or there. Its either the instructions are outdated or it just works for that specific setup.

I tried following this guide as its posted everywhere on the interwebs:

> Installation is done via the awesome new "pipe into sh" route:
>
> curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable Load it:
>
> source ~/.rvm/scripts/'rvm' If you want to use version 1.9. 3, just go
>   ahead and:
>
> rvm use 1.9. 3 Want to test with 1.9. 2? Sure:
>
> rvm use 1.9. 2 Commands like gem also work right out of the box:
>
> gem install rails That's it. You're done. You no longer have to deal
>   with the frustration that arises from using distro-built ruby
>   packages.

I'm sorry but that didn't work as after doing source it throws "no such file or directory". So am I suppose to create the directory manually? Or was something else suppose to do that? The instructions doesn't specify. I find it so frustrating when installing stuff like this on Linux as there is always some weird quirk that prevents the full installation. Sure I can continue googling and find other instructions and constantly copy/paste into my terminal in hopes that something sticks and it all of a sudden works, but have no idea what happen due to massive copy/pasting spam.

Another option I was thinking, maybe I should just uninstall ruby and whatever else is related to it? And install it from scratch? So do I just do a **apt-get uninstall ruby**? I doubt its that simple to uninstall right? =)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (From the [official install guide](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)):

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Notice the `\` which is done to make sure your using the `curl` binary and not an alias.  See [Why start a shell command with a backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691977/why-start-a-shell-command-with-a-backslash).  As a hunch, if the command is failing, curl is aliased.

Comment: thanks.. just tried your command and i get this: http://prntscr.com/5p1e1c ... -_-

Comment: Post the output of `ls ~/rvm`